# autocomplete select listener

Tags: jboss, jsf-2, richfaces, java-ee-6

I would like to use a method in rich:autocomplete component much the same way like ValueChangeListener, the problem is that I cannot submit the form in order for the Listener to get fired, that's why I wanted to ask you how could I intercept an event in order to execute a Listener in my backing bean. I have tried this:

```
<rich:autocomplete id="autocompleteOficina" 
  value="#{agenciaDM.oficinaSeleccionada}" converter="entityConverter"
  autocompleteList="#{suggestionEntitiesDM.availableEntitiesList(suggestionEntitiesDM.oficina)}"
  var="oficina" fetchValue="#{oficina.label}" showButton="true">
  <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{oficinaController.empresaSearchSelectedListener}"></a4j:ajax>
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{oficina.label}" />
  </rich:column>
</rich:autocomplete>
```

I have also tried the select event, but no one executed the Listener, why is it not fired?.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please enclose it inside

```
<h:form></h:form>
```

Also please check the listener method signature in the backing bean